# Moving a few select DB tables to a new WP instance

Tags: plugins, php, database, mysql

I’m currently in the process of building a new WP site for a client. The backend is going to be the same it’s just a front end update. Unfortunately due to certain factors we have have to build the site on a different sever and WP version ect.

My issue is that the website uses a plugin called WP-Client. This have and import/export feature which have unfortunately let me down and on importing the exported data from the old site the csv file is getting changed to Chinese looking symbols and as a result I can’t import any data.

I’m thinking of just moving the plugin data in the current live tables and put it in the new dev database. Is this reasonable to do or is this going to cause big issues? I might also need to move the users tables also.

Any plugins for moving single tables? My MySQL is not the best.

Comment: You don't want to just migrate the entire DB?  Then you could delete pages or whatever else.  Migrating user from site to site is easy, there are a ton of plugins for that.  Plugin data could be difficult depending.

Comment: @RiddleMeThis  My worry is that with the WP versions are different so I might have issues and with different themes using different tables ect. I was thinking be best just to move the needed tables

Comment: even if you could figure where everything for your plugins is stored, grab all that and import it, you will probably run into issues with ID and keys used throughout.

Comment: Why can't you use the same version of WP on the dev site? Then you can pull in the entire database and avoid a lot of headaches.

Comment: @WebElaine It’s looking like that might be the best course of action. It just means redoing a lot of the front end but If it saves time and headaches in the long run I’m up for it!

Comment: Using the same version of Core and plugins will almost certainly save time and headaches.